# Subprocesses complete but do not exit when using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have my demo code shown as below. I realize that all subprocesses have finished but they do not exit. Is there anything wrong with my code? Python version: 3.7.4, Operation system: win10

```
import multiprocessing as mp

res_queue = mp.Queue()

def runCalculation(i):
    count_list = []
    total_count = i

    for k in range(100000):
        total_count += k
        count_list.append(total_count)
    print('task {} finished calculation, putting results to queue'.format(i))

    for item in count_list: res_queue.put(item)
    print('task {} has put all results to queue'.format(i))


def initPool(res_queue_):
    global res_queue
    res_queue = res_queue_


def mainFunc():

    p = mp.Pool(initializer=initPool, initargs=(res_queue,))
    for i in range(20): p.apply_async(runCalculation, args=(i,))

    print('Waiting for all subprocesses done...')
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print('All subprocesses done.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainFunc()
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "complete but do not exit"?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma all subprocesses printed 'task {} has put all results to queue' which means they have complete, but 'all subprocesses done.' in the mainFunc() was not printed and the python interpreter was still waiting